# Normal distribution issues - Log transformations versus distribution fitting

Tags: r, normal-distribution, biostatistics, boxcox-transformation

Context: I want to know if the position of the CWD significantly influences Grass Height. I have 2 variables:
1.) a continuous response variable called Grass Height (cm)
2.) a categorical predictor variable called CWD Type (short for coarse woody debris type) and it has 3 levels: (open, above ground and cage).

[image]

Grass height is not normally distributed. I did the log+1 transformation and it is still not normally distributed as seen by the qqnorm plot below:

[image]

So I decided to assess which distribution would fit the best using the following code:

```
require(car)
require(MASS)
qqp(GrassHeight,"norm")
qqp(GrassHeight,"lnorm")
nbinom<-fitdistr(GrassHeight,"Negative Binomial")
qqp(GrassHeight,"nbinom",size=nbinom$estimate[[1]],
        mu=nbinom$estimate[[2]])
 poisson<-fitdistr(GrassHeight,"Poisson")
 qqp(GrassHeight,"pois",poisson$estimate)
 gamma<-fitdistr(GrassHeight,"gamma")
 qqp(GrassHeight,"gamma",shape=gamma$estimate[[1]],
        rate=gamma$estimate[[2]])
```

However, my data does not fall between the two lines at all for any of the above distributions.

Please advise me on what to do.

A boxcox transformation of (GrassHeight+1~CWDPosition) shows this graph:

[image]

the normality plot for the -1/3 transformation:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dominique and welcome to the site. It sounds to me that you ultimately  want to perform an ANOVA or regression analysis to check your hypothesis. Both of those analyses don't require the original variables to be normally distributed. Rather, the *residuals* are assumed to be approximately normal distributed. So my advice would be to perform your analyses and check the residuals.

Comment: @COOLSerdash, hello and thank you! So I did what you said:

`model<-aov(GrassHeight~CWDPosition)`
`summary(model)`
`qqnorm(resid(model))`
`qqline(resid(model))`

And the residuals are not normally distributed as well. I then ran a Kruskal-Wallis Test on the non-parametric data which shows that CWD type significantly affects grass height but then when I try run a Tukey HSD post hoc test, it produces a p-value of 0 for all 3 positions

Comment: Also, you can still use box-cox, there is no prohibition then against  a categorical predictor. Also, ANOVA still makes sense when the errors have other than normal distribution (but might not be optimal).  You could still get corect confidence intervals by using the bootstrap!

Comment: You can also give us access to the data, and we can have a look ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, thanks for your suggestion. How would I structure the boxcox transformation then? Is boxcox(GrassHeight~CWDType) sufficient? It wont run as I have zero values and it needs to be positive so I added 1 to GrassHeight and then it ran. How do I interpret the graph? The 3 dotted lines are between 0 and -1 but closer to 0. Do I need to specify the range of lambda values?

Comment: Can you show us the graph you got?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, i edited my question and uploaded the boxcox transformation image there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45231/discussion-between-dominique-and-kjetil-b-halvorsen).

Comment: That plot shows the estimated value (center line, $\hat{\lambda}$  close ti -1/3, the two other neighboring vertival lines showing limits of a 95% confidence interval, which is quite narrow!  You could try ANOVA with a power of -1/3, even if that gives a transformation difficult to interpret.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, so I did this: `GH<-(GrassHeight+1)^-1/3
model<-aov(GH~CWDPosition)
summary(model)
qqnorm(resid(model))
qqline(resid(model))
The aov results are:
Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
CWDPosition 2 0.185 0.09269 51.56 <2e-16 ***
Residuals 1927 3.464 0.00180
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`
However the normal Q-Q plot is definitely not normal

Comment: Can you describe the sort of non-normality? Is it heavy tails? then maybe some other error distribution is called for, maybe we try an identy link GLM with some other error distribution, or you could try the bootstrap, if the problem is not heavy tails.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I have uploaded the normality plot for the -1/3 transformation above. Can we move this to chat then I can perhaps send you the data?

Comment: Non-normality does not appear to be an issue: the plot alone shows a strong relationship between CWD and grass height.  Maybe it's time to move on.